# How many outputs possible when throwing $m$ balls into $n$ bins?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

For example, for $3$ balls and $3$ bins we have:

```
1: 1 2 3 (one ball in every bin)
2: 1 2 2
3: 1 3 3 
4: 2 1 1
5: 2 3 3 
6: 3 1 1
7: 3 2 2
8: 1 1 1 
9: 2 2 2 
10:3 3 3 (three balls in the third bin)
```

What is theory for it? I mean, that is the name of the formula, to let me read about it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. In option 1 you seem to have 6 balls total, while in option 10 you seem to have 9 balls total... Or do you mean throw at least 1 and at most $m$ into each bin?

Comment: Please see [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) on  Wikipedia.

Comment: @DennisGulko , thanks i edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you study the [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.  In this case, you have three bins (2 bars) and three balls (three stars).  This gives 3 + 2 = 5 positions.  You can place the 2 bars in *any* of the 5 positions which gives $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ possibilities or you can place the 3 stars in any of the 5 positions: $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ possibilities:

$$
1: 0|0|3\rightarrow ||*** \\
2: 0|1|2\rightarrow |*|**\\
3: 0|2|1\rightarrow |**|* \\
4: 0|3|0\rightarrow |***| \\
5: 1|0|2\rightarrow *||** \\
6: 1|1|1\rightarrow *|*|* \\
7: 1|2|0\rightarrow *|**| \\
8: 2|0|1\rightarrow **||* \\
9: 2|1|0\rightarrow **|*| \\
10: 3|0|0\rightarrow ***||
$$

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to throw exactly $k$ balls total into $n$ bins without restriction is equal to the number of ways to order $k$ stars and $n-1$ bars in line, where all the stars are identical and all the bars are identical, so the number would be:
$$\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}=\binom{k+n-1}{k}$$
As you only need to choose the place for the stars (or the bars).
If you want each bin to be non-empty, throw $1$ ball into each first, and then throw the remaining $k-n$ balls, so the number would be 
$$\binom{(k-n)+n-1}{n-1}=\binom{k-1}{n-1}$$
Now, if I understand your question correctly, you want all possible ways to throw any number of balls into $n$ bins such that each bin would contain at least $1$ ball and at most $m$. Using the above formula, we get:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{m\cdot n}\binom{k-1}{n-1}$$